# BEM nesting naming convention - grandchild element

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child, bem

I have the follwing html

```
<div class="listing listing--with-margin">
    @foreach($recipients as $recipent)
      <span class="listing__item">{{ $recipent }} <input type="checkbox"></span>
      <span class="listing__item">{{ $recipent  }} <input type="checkbox"></span>
    @endforeach
```

Should the class on the checkbox be

```
<input type="checkbox" class="listing__input">
```

or

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="listing__item listing__input">
```

I think option 1 which allows me to write is a lot cleaner in the sass with less nesting.

Comment: The first one. The second option would give both the `span` and `input` the class `listing__item` - which I assume you wouldn't want?

Comment: definitely, the first one. The second variant is called `mixin`, and it's not suitable here

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the Naming page in the BEM [documentation](http://getbem.com/naming/), at the bottom you'll see an example section, with a form block.

In the example, you will find the `<form>` element, with a couple of `<input />`s.

Each `<input>` has its *own* element class of either `.form__input` or `.form__submit`, both inheriting from the block `.form` class. They do not inherit more than **one** class.

However, you will notice that they have multiple modifier classes, which is acceptable.

Comment: `<input>` does not use a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854998/8375199) answer, an `input` is a void element, the closing slash is optional. However, for best practice, I have removed the slash in the answer.

Comment: Yes and the closing slash does nothing, means nothing, is not specified for the element itself and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So it has no value and is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options for grandchildren element.

- Flattening grandchildren

```
<article class="post">
  <div class="post__meta">
    <div class="post__category">...</div>
    <div class="post__date">...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</article>
```

- Creating new blocks

```
<article class="post">
  <div class="post__meta">
    <div class="category post__category">...</div>
    <div class="date post__date">...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</article>
```

- Extending the BEM naming convention

```
<article class="post">
  <div class="post__meta">
    <div class="post__meta__category">...</div>
    <div class="post__meta__date">...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</article>
```